# How to place my function using QSignalMapper and QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, arguments, signals-slots, qsignalmapper

I'm a beginner in c++.

i'm trying to pass an argument using QSignalMapper. I do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(0);
    QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int )), 0 ,SLOT(mySlot(int )));

    int prova=11;
    mapper->setMapping(but, prova);
    QObject::connect(but, SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
    
   //do stuff
}
```

Where i can put mySlot()? I need to pass the variable "prova"
Thanks to all.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to do more. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: when i click on button "but", i want to send to mySlot() an int value in order to do some calculations

Comment: The mapping will send a fixed value to the slot for the last time you executed setMapping(). I am curious where and how the `prova`  value gets set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about QSignalMapper and use lambdas:

```
QObject::connect(but, &QButton::clicked, myObject, [myObject,prova]() { myObject->mySlot(prova); });
```

In case `mySlot` is just a regular function:

```
QObject::connect(but, &QButton::clicked, [prova]() { mySlot(prova); });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm try to implement your solution. What i have to put in myObject? Then, can you please link me some documentations? thank you!

Comment: `myObject` would be an instance of an object that hosts `mySlot`. If it is just a plain function, see edit.

Comment: i've implemented your information in the main class: ` QObject::connect(but, &QPushButton::clicked,  [ prova]() {
   
    }); ` just like this and it works! do you think is good? thank you so much!